# How to send sms automatically after a certain time/ after fixed day using nodeJs, mongodb crud? Who can help me?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud

I want to send sms automatically after a certain time/after fixed day. I'm using mongodb crud,  node js.  I'm a new learner.  This is first I'm doing this project. I'm trying for a few day to do this but I couldn't find any solution. Is there anyone here who can help me?

Comment: In order to send an SMS by software you usually need to buy such a service from a mobile phone provider.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda.
It uses mongodb and you can schedule your tasks with your custom logic. I think the example below is similar to what you are looking for. It's from the package's official README file.

```
agenda.define(
  "send email report",
  { priority: "high", concurrency: 10 },
  async (job) => {
    const { to } = job.attrs.data;
    await emailClient.send({
      to,
      from: "example@example.com",
      subject: "Email Report",
      body: "...",
    });
  }
);

(async function () {
  await agenda.start();
  await agenda.schedule("in 20 minutes", "send email report", {
    to: "admin@example.com",
  });
})();
```

Comment: Dear @archon, I have some records in the database. Each record has a specific date attribute, the attributes are different. I want to send an SMS on that date to the phone. Actually, I want to do this. Maybe I had made the question wrong. I should have written in detail. Can you help me about this?

Comment: @KarnojitRoyHimaloy Since I don't know your usecase completely, what I can offer is to use the logic above. The simplest way to schedule an SMS for every existing account by a script would be to make a foreach loop on all accounts, then get the specific date attribute, then make a `schedule` based on the date attribute.

You'd have to define (as in the start of the code I shared) your logic for sending an SMS.

Comment: @Okay. Let me try dear. Thank you so much